# How do you add an icon on a gcc created application?

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, compilation, icons

I have been working for a few weeks now using straight gcc terminal compiling instead of an IDE. Why? No clue actually, just felt like it. I want to be able to set an icon for the compiled application though and i can't find anything on the subject except for windows based tutorials using the .rc files and winres. Is there any way to achieve this using terminal commands? If so, how would I go about doing it.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Ok, so I guess I didn't explain this very well in hindsight. I want to be able to compile a gcc application on ubuntu but I want it to have an icon on the final product. I want something other then the default icon that shows up. How might I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you asking about windows or ubuntu?

Comment: for [Linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/119031/how-to-set-my-applications-desktop-icon-for-linux-kde-gnome-etc) and for [windows](http://fragglet.livejournal.com/4448.html)  Is this what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

When using the command line to create an application on Windows you end up with something like **filename.exe** It sounds like what you want is an icon on the desktop that you can double  click to run the program. To do this, right click your mouse on a location on your desktop that is just part of the background, select **new** then **shortcut** and fill in the blanks. Then right click on the new icon created for you, then click on **properties** then on the properties window click on **change icon** and fill in the blanks. The file type of the icon must be ico such as **myicon.ico**.